# Why is everything in minecraft opaque red and blue?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have updated my drivers, updated java, restarted my computer and downloaded the game several times. When I try to play the game everything is duplicated in opaque red and blue. Does anyone else have this problem?

Comment: Sounds like you just turned every video option "on" without knowing what they did. This isn't a good policy. :)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie that may be true but the question is valid. "I have this problem, I have tried these things, please help." +1

Comment: @Alex Oh yeah, not saying it isn't. :)

Comment: @jdpower Are you using an m1 mac?

Answer (score 25):

Turn off the 3D Anaglyph option in the Options > Video Settings screen.